# jQuery, text match defaults select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

Using: Rails and jQuery

I have a form with a Url textbox input in which a user can put a url such as:

http://www.webshop.com/article/123

url is an attribute of @product.

In the same form I also have a dropdown populated with stores (Store.all). The store has an attribute store.short_url that could be "www.webshop.com".

I want to use jQuery so that when a user types in http://www.webshop.com/article/123 in the url-textbox I want to compare that with the Store objects and see if that store is in the database which short_url matches the domain name and if so, default that Store in the dropdown.

The string matching should not be a problem but how do I handle this in jQuery?

1. Fill out the url field
2. When text field is out of focus do:
3. Find Store with matching url
4. Set that store as default

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic gist:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#url_input').change(function(){
    var urlPattern = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+)([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/
        if(urlPattern.test($(this).val())){
            alert('hurray');
            url = ($(this).val().match(urlPattern))[2].toLowerCase();
            $('option[value="'+url+'"]','#available_types').each(function(){$(this).attr('selected',true)});
        }
    });
    });
    ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sScma/2/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use it exactly as you put it (handled the urlPattern in Rails instead) but it got me to where I needed to be.